# Multi threading with non-void functions

Tags: c++, multithreading, opencv

I'm trying to multi thread my program in C++ (I use OpenCV libraries)
This is the code:

```
double _find_eyes (Mat img, vector<Rect_<int> > & finalEyes)
{
//some code working on image
return valueOfMatch; //is a double
}

double _find_mouth (Mat img, vector<Rect_<int> > & finalMouth)
{
//some code working on image
return valueOfMatch; //is a double
}

double _find_face ()
{
eyesMatch = _find_eyes(image, eye);
mouthMatch = _find_mouth(image, mouth);
totalMatch = eyesMatch + mouthMatch;
}

int main()
{
find_face();
}
```

I would like to find mouth and eyes in a parallel way using threads. How to do it? My problems are on non-void functions and the return value.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One easy way is to use [`std::async`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/async), e.g.:

```
double _find_face ()
{
    auto eyesMatch = std::async(std::launch::async, _find_eyes, std::ref(image), std::ref(eye));
    auto mouthMatch = std::async(std::launch::async, _find_mouth, std::ref(image), std::ref(mouth));
    return eyesMatch.get() + mouthMatch.get();
}
```

Comment: I did what you suggest, but it gives me this   `error: reference to non-static member function must be called  auto eyesMatch = async(launch::async, _find_eyes, ref(image), ref(eye));`  and the same for mouth.. Any suggestion? –

Comment: @JackJack Post complete code next time.
`std::async(std::launch::async, &MyClass::_find_eyes, this, std::ref(image), std::ref(eye))` and `std::async(std::launch::async, &MyClass::_find_mouth, this, std::ref(image), std::ref(mouth))`. Replace `MyClass` with whatever your class name is.